# Mongoose ValidatorError even though fields are provided and non-null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I got an "interesting" issue when trying to add a new user using my API... I get the following error, even though the required fields are submitted. I can't really figure out why. I've added the relevant part of the code. Thanks.

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:3000/api/users --data "{ 'user_name':'xsa', 'email':'foo@bar.baz' }"
```

The error:

```
{"errors":{"email":{"message":"Path `email` is required.","name":"ValidatorError","properties":{"message":"Path `{PATH}` is required.","type":"required","path":"email"},"kind":"required","path":"email","$isValidatorError":true}},"_message":"User validation failed","message":"User validation failed: email: Path `email` is required.","name":"ValidationError"}
```

models/user.js

```
[...]

user_name: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    required: true,
    index: {
      unique: true
    },
    trim: true,
    min: 3,
    max: 8
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    required: true
  },

[...]
```

routes/user.js

```
router.post('/users', (req, res, err) => {
  var user = new User(req.body);

  user.save()
    .catch((err) => {
      res.send(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you look at req.body in your route to confirm your data is there?

Comment: @JeffMatthews I knew the data was there, in `req.body` -- Now I checked the `user` variable... and the data I'm passing is not there. It seems it's lost somewhere in between then...

Comment: Now, you at least see that you need to trace to find out where it is missing.  I'd suggest you look at req.body.  If it is there, then, check your new User() to see that it receives the parameter and assigns the values correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
var user = new User(req.body);
```

Change to this:

```
var user = new User();
user.name - req.body.name;
user.email = req.body.email;
```

Edit:  Here is HTML form:

```
<div>

    <form method="post" action="/users/save">

        <div>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type='text' required name="userName"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type='text' required name="email"/>
        </div>

    <input type="submit" class="submit btn btn-primary" value="Save">

    </form>
</div>
```

When user presses submit button, your req.body is send neatly to your router.  You will have req.body.userName and req.body.email waiting for you.

I removed a lot of CSS to make it easier to read.  Apply your own styling as desired.

Comment: Tried that too. No dice. Same thing. It only show the default that I set in my model, nothing that I submitted.

Comment: You are saying that the value of req.body.email is there, but when you assign it to user.email, user.email still remains empty?

Comment: Actually, when I print to the console `req.body` I get the following output: `{ '{ user_name:xsa, email:foo@bar.baz }': '' }` ... but when I print `req.body.email` it's undefined... Maybe the format of the data I pass is wrong?

Comment: You are correct.  Wrong format.  In my HTML views, each input (text, selects, etc.) has a name attribute.  I have a submit button with all the inputs inside a form.  On submit, the form is submitted, and the router receives req.body.  There is a req.body.<name> for the name of each html input.  Make sense?

Comment: Yeah. Looks like it comes from the request, the issue. Thanks for your time Jeff.

Answer (score 0):

There are name tags in the form where you get data on the html page. You should not leave any spaces when typing these name tags. At the same time, the nomenclature here should be the same as in the model.

I lost half an hour because of a null character I didn't notice.